# Mailchimp v2.0 exception manipulation

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am using this code to subscribe the posted email.

```
<?
    $api_key = "apikey";
    $list_id = "listid";
    $gotemail = $_POST['email'];

    require('src/Mailchimp.php');
    $Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
    $Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists( $Mailchimp );
    $subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe( $list_id, array( 'email' => $gotemail ) );
?>
```

Now, What should I do to check if there is any error, and if it is, block it from exiting the script (killing it and printing the error on screen)? Like just save it in a variable and use it later.

Comment: I am interested in solving the same problem if you found any solution please share!